# Should (ccm) be used (use-ccm="true") in production environments

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am using Jboss EAP version in Production. So I want to know what is the use f use-ccm param and it is advisable to keep if false in production

Answer (score 0):

cached connection manager's default value is true. According to RedHat its use is normal for production systems. Please check following link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/309913